# Show php image field only uploaded field

Tags: php, css

i have 3 image field like this

```
<?php echo $row['thumbnail1']; ?>
<?php echo $row['thumbnail2']; ?>
<?php echo $row['thumbnail3']; ?>
```

if there only one exp thumbnail1 is have image..

how to show

and how if only image 1 and 2 have data..

please help how to show php query if there only 1 or 2 and 3 image upload

this css style

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
   </div>

<!-- IF only 2 image available uploaded USE this -->                                                                        

 <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>

<!-- IF only ALL/3 image available uploaded USE this -->        

<div class="col-xs-4">
     <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>  
 <div class="col-xs-4">
       <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

dsa sdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace your old code with this (Someone edited So i have Re writtent the code again) :**

```
<?php
if(isset($row['thumbnail1']))
{
?>
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
   </div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- IF only 2 image available uploaded USE this -->                                                                        
<?php
if(isset($row['thumbnail2']))
{
?>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- IF only ALL/3 image available uploaded USE this -->        
<?php
if(isset($row['thumbnail3']))
{
?>
<div class="col-xs-4">
     <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
      <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>  
 <div class="col-xs-4">
       <a href="#"><img src="#" class="w-full"></a>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Give me the update, if you have tested.

Comment: sorry bro.. swear i don't do click.. i think it cliked.. :)

btw i mean like this.. https://pasteboard.co/GJXkHrr.png

Comment: Hi Javas, I have re written due to the post has been edited. So Have you replaced the code with the new one ? Give a Test and update me the result.